# Discrete Math Anne likes Dave but Dave likes someone else.///(b) There is an integer that is smaller than or equal to all integers.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

This is what i have so far, I am fairly certain it is correct but would like to ask for any help if it is not

3)  (a)Let L(x,y) mean x likes y L(Anne,Dave) ^ ∃yL(Dave,y)

(b)  ∃x∀y(x≤y)

any help is appreciated thank you!!

Comment: We’ve dealt with (a) in the other question; (b) is correct, assuming that it’s understood that the variables $x$ and $y$ range over the integers.

Comment: Don't post the same question twice.